# My netbook volume + and volume - buttons stopped working after 12.04 update

Tags: volume-control

That's it...

Brightness buttons are still working great but volume button simply won't do anything...

What can I do?

Thanks.

ps

I have an Asus 1215n and Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it sounds STRANGE but it worked :/

I booted into windows (from hybernating state) and keys and keys were also dead there.

I've rebooted windows normally and keys were back working.

I've rebooted Ubuntu and keys were also working there.

:/